# Unexpected behavior of JAX `vmap` for multiple arguments

Tags: python, arrays, vectorization, jax

I have found that `vmap` in JAX does not behave as expected when applied to multiple arguments. For example, consider the function below:

```
def f1(x, y, z):
    f = x[:, None, None] * z[None, None, :] + y[None, :, None]
    return f
```

For `x = jnp.arange(7), y = jnp.arange(5), z = jnp.arange(3)`, the output of this function has shape `(7, 5, 3)`. However, for the vmap version below:

```
@partial(vmap, in_axes=(None, 0, 0), out_axes=(1, 2))
def f2(x, y, z):
    f = x*z + y
    return f
```

It outputs this error:

```
ValueError: vmap got inconsistent sizes for array axes to be mapped:
  * one axis had size 5: axis 0 of argument y of type int32[5];
  * one axis had size 3: axis 0 of argument z of type int32[3]
```

Could someone kindly explain what's behind this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The semantics of `vmap` are that it does a single batching operation along one or more arrays. When you specify `in_axes=(None, 0, 0)`, the meaning is "map simultaneously along the leading dimension of `y` and `z`": the error you're seeing is telling you that the leading dimensions of `y` and `z` have different sizes, and so they are not compatible for batching.

Your function `f1` essentially uses broadcasting to encode three batching operations, so to replicate that logic with `vmap` you'll need three applications of `vmap`. You can express that as follows:

```py
@partial(vmap, in_axes=(0, None, None))
@partial(vmap, in_axes=(None, 0, None))
@partial(vmap, in_axes=(None, None, 0))
def f2(x, y, z):
    f = x*z + y
    return f
```